# Elephant garlic Allium ampeloprasum struggling, difficiencies?

Tags: nutrients, ph, garlic, deficiency

I noticed that these Allium ampeloprasum started a couple months ago, are struggling and showing some deficiencies that I can't pinpoint.

My soil is sandy and poor, with pH slightly over 8. I gave it plenty of NPK, but I have a doubt that it's missing some micros. Notice the spiraling and yellowing of the leaf.

[image]
[image]
[image]